# Extjs: grid crashes because of the Ext.grid.column.Widget

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, widget, extjs6

Good day everybody!

I have created an Ext.grid.column.Widget in **beforerender** event of a **Ext.grid.Panel** component:

```
var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Widget', {
                text  : '...',
                width : 200,
                onWidgetAttach: function(column, widget, record) {
                     // simple operations
                },
                widget: {
                    xtype   : 'button',
                    text    : '...',
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(me, event, eOpts) {
                            // simple operations
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then I'm attaching this to a main Ext.grid.Panel component:

```
grid.headerCt.insert(2, column);
```

On this stage everything is nice, column with buttons are shown and acts well, but...

There is some additional functionality - window which is opened by clicking on other cell (gridcolumn), it uses **ViewController** and on **onCellclick** it calls:

```
record.callJoined('afterCommit', [fieldName]);
```

And then a crash: [image: Chrome crash pic]

Tracing shows that crash occurs here (ext-all-rtl-debug.js):

```
updateColumns: function(oldRow, newRow, columnsToUpdate, record) {
...
// Replace changed cells in the existing row structure with the new version
// from the rendered row.
for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
    column = columnsToUpdate[colIndex];
    // Pluck out cells using the column's unique cell selector.
    // Because in a wrapped row, there may be several TD elements.
    cellSelector = me.getCellSelector(column);
    oldCell = oldRow.querySelector(cellSelector);
    newCell = newRow.querySelector(cellSelector);
    // Copy new cell attributes across.
    newAttrs = newCell.attributes; // HERE IS THE CLUE????
    attLen = newAttrs.length;
    for (attrIndex = 0; attrIndex < attLen; attrIndex++) {
        attName = newAttrs[attrIndex].name;
        value = newAttrs[attrIndex].value;
        if (attName !== 'id' && oldCell.getAttribute(attName) !== value) {
            oldCell.setAttribute(attName, value);
        }
    }
```

`console.log(newCell.attributes)` shows such gridcolumn attributes:
[image: console.log]

But on a widget column it seems attributes variable equal to null.

I noticed that grid.columns array contains only gridcolumns and not contains widgetcolumn.

What I need to do to solve the error?

This is a huge project with dynamic grid constructor so I can't produce it in fiddle.

Comment: Any working fiddle to showcase your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding necessary parameter to Ext.grid.column.Widget object:

```
dataIndex: 'WidgetColumn',
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use [`reconfigure`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) method instead of using private attributes like `headerCt` (in my opinion is bad idea)?

Use it like:
`grid.reconfigure(columns);`

It need to be in `beforerender` event? I propose to override `initComponent` function.